# How to display a related Contact's Participant Custom Field in a View

Tags: drupal-views

Using Drupal Views, I want to display a Parent custom field in a Children list.

I can display (e.g.) : (CiviCRM Contact B) CiviCRM Contacts: Sort Name (Parent)

But if I want to display (CiviCRM Contact B) CiviCRM Custom: Infos Parents Participants: Préférence de clocher (Préférence de clocher), (which is a Participant Custom Field), I get an empty column

Is it possible to solve that ?

Comment: Did you tried using relationships in view?

Comment: Yes, I did : CiviCRM Contacts: CiviCRM Relationship (starting from contact A) and (CiviCRM Relationship (starting from contact A)) CiviCRM Relationships: Contact ID B. I can add the pertaining field, but get the column empty (without any error message).

Comment: At the field level did you also set the contact to use the Contact ID B?

Comment: Yes, of course.