# How to copy a Custom Field in a related Contact's Custom Field?

Tags: webform-civicrm, civirules

I use a Webform to register both Parent and related Children to an Event.

I would like them to **share** a common Participant Custom Field information : this does not seem possible, since each Participant has his own.

I think of different options, but I don't know if they are possible :

**Option 1 :** in the Webform : set Child field i to Parent field j Value : but, as far as I know, this is not possible with the standard Webform Conditionals ; is there any Webform extension to do that ?

**Option 2 :** independantly from Webform : create a Rule (?) (and a CRON Job ?) to copy Parent field j Value to his related Children's fields i. But I don't know wether this is possible, nor how to do that.

Any help or suggestion is welcome (I am not a developper)

Comment: Can you use registered by participant? I mean have custom field for Parent and then create a participant for child and link to parent participant ID.

Comment: As far as I understand what you mean, it is what I do : One Webform to register Parent AND children, with "Register each Contact separately" method + Particpant custom field for Parent + relationship to Parent for each Child. I want Children to share (or copy) the Parent Participant Custom Field.

Comment: I don't think this something easily doable through UI configuration. But do possible by writing a extension or module. Wait for someone in the community to answer or provide any other solutions

Comment: Is your participant custom field a select element? If yes, maybe add webform conditional for all the options present. If not, you might need to add a markup field and add a small js to copy the value from one field to another.

Answer (score 0):

The option of creating a rule is a probably an easy solution. There is a Drupal module to have a tirgger in civirules when a webform is submitted (https://lab.civicrm.org/partners/civicoop/webform_civirules)

Why do you want to store the information twice in your system and only ask once?

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions ; I finally opted for the webform Conditional as suggested by Jitendra (and which I did not think of before) : I set the Child field value (textfield) according to the Parent field selected value (select field) : it is a bit heavy to implement (several values and several children in the webform), but it has the advantage to have all in one webform : easier to test and maintain. But I would be pleased to validate all the proposed solutions.

Comment: Jaap : I need to store the info related to each participant because the information belongs to all the related participants : Parent AND children : if I question a child, I want to get the information. + using Views, I did not find a way to display a custom field from a related participant : see https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/26267/how-to-display-a-related-contacts-participant-custom-field-in-a-view

Comment: Ah I see. So the reason for storing it multiple times is because it is hard to show them in a view. Understandable. I have also commented on your other topic.

Comment: Jacques would be good for you to add your own Answer and Accept it so this Q has an answer